# eth0 static ip resetting to dhcp upon VM reboot

Tags: networking, dhcp, cloud, static-ip

I am facing an eth ip setting issue where upon reboot the static ip is bieng removed and dhcp is bieng applied .

Env : RHEL 7.6

```
**ETH configuration before reboot** :

    [root@bdnlsit-eda2 ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
    NETMASK=255.255.255.240
    BOOTPROTO=static
    DEVICE=eth0
    IPADDR=10.74.41.37
    ONBOOT=yes
    NOZEROCONF=yes

**ETH Configuration after reboot** :

 [root@bdnlsit-eda2~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
    # Created by cloud-init on instance boot automatically, do not edit.
    #
    BOOTPROTO=dhcp
    DEVICE=eth0
    HWADDR=00:50:56:b8:79:47
    ONBOOT=yes
    TYPE=Ethernet
    USERCTL=no
```

Any suggestions on how to rectify this and set the static ip for eth0 on boot .

Answer (score 2):

The clue is in the file you've pasted, it was edited by 'cloud-init'.

The [documentation page](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/network-config.html#disabling-network-configuration) for cloud-init shows you can disable the network configuration using the command

`network-config={config: disabled}` which should be entered into various different configuration files, depending exactly how your instance is setup.
Without knowing exactly where the instance you are firing up has come from, it's impossible to tell you exactly which file you should edit, however the documentation covers many options.

Comment: Thanks for your input djsmiley2k. But as I checked cloud-init documentation online , the suggested resolution spans across multiple config file changes . Am confused which one to use as the system is a critical enterprise test bed and need to be sure before applying any boot level changes

Comment: That'll depend on how cloud-init is setup on your system. It's like me saying I want to edit how X works. X can be configured by about 5 different files to start with, then hundreds more options if you chose to enable them. No one else can tell me how my system is configured without me explaining first.